# change layouts based on android os version

Tags: android

To avoid having to manually check on every activity if I'm Jellybean or not and pick layouts accordingly (because the ActionBar takes up more space than the old title bar), is there a simple way to specify layout files by os in the same way you can specify layout files by screen size by naming the folders?

Comment: I would also add that if the small number of pixels difference between the ActionBar and the title breaks your layout, you might want to make it more flexible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a Platform Version Level qualifier.  The official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

It would look like `layout-v<API Level>`

An example:

```
layout-v11/  Honeycomb+
layout-v14/  ICS+
```